# Option for Include to only return foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework-5

Does Entity Framework provide an option to retrieve child objects that are only populated with fields that are foreign keys to the parent object?

Sample code might illustrate this better.

Assuming you have the following POCO classes...

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : Base
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Photo : Base
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User UploadedBy { get; set; }
}
```

... and assuming you've configured a `DbContext` correctly, how do you query for a list of all `Photos` including the `UploadedBy` object, but where that `UploadedBy` object only contains the `Id` property?

I know I can do this...

```
return await _dbContext.Photos.Include(p => p.UploadedBy).ToListAsync();
```

... but that returns the entire `User` object.

I'd like to do something like this...

```
return await _dbContext.Photos.Include(p => p.UploadedBy.Id).ToListAsync();
```

... to indicate that I only want the `Id` property back.

If we could chain those includes we would be able to pick each property on the child object that we want returned.

Or even better, I'd love to be able to configure a setting at a more global level that would make it so that anytime I ask for `Photos`, give me all members of photos, even child objects, but only populate their foreign keys and nothing more.

The last request is less important though because I could just create the following extension method for each POCO object...

```
   public static IQueryable<Photo> IncludeForigenKeys(this PhotoAlbumDbContext context){
         return context.Photos
             .Include(photo => photo.UploadedBy.Id);
     }
```

Comment: I dont believe so. However you can include the keys on your model which will mean that you dont need to use the remote end of the FK. Eg. `public int UploadedById { get; set; } public User UploadedBy { get; set; }` this is how I achieve this particular result

Comment: Thanks Luke, that's a good point.  I'm curious how you handle having two places where the FK is stored.  How do downstream apps know which place to retrieve the id?  Do you always populate both?  Is there some convention/scenario where you know to access UploadedById vs UploadedBy.Id?

Comment: EF is pretty clever around this, if you populate it in either place and save changes it will take the changed value. when you load the entity without the navigation property it will populate the FK with the correct ID and the nav property as null. This kinda means people downstream can access either property, if they want to load the full nav property they can use the remote one or if they want to avoid that load then they can use the local one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand there is no way to partially load a Navigation Property.

However for foreign keys the standard way of accessing these without loading the Nav property is to include the actual key in your model. Eg:

```
public class Photo : Base
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int UploadedById { get; set; }
    public User UploadedBy { get; set; }
}
```

This id will be populated even if you don't actually load the whole navigation property.

In the case where you load both you can update either the value on the local or remote end of the nav property and that update will be persisted to the database on save. In my experience EF is very clever around this. The only scenario where it becomes a little more tricky is in unit tests where EF is not maintaining this state.

Comment: Thanks Luke!  I'm going with this approach.

Comment: @paul no problems glad to help